# Calling certain functions when initializing a new mongoengine document

Tags: python, mongoengine

I'm trying to define a Document class that has some fields that have their values automatically calculated when a new document is created.
So far I have succeeded in doing that by extending the `__init__` function like this:

```
class URLDoc(Document):
    url = fields.URLField(requierd=True)
    domain = fields.StringField(required=True)
    screenshot = fields.ImageField(required=True, size=(600, 600, True), thumbnail=(100, 100, True))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(URLDoc, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.domain = urlparse(self.url).netloc
        self.get_and_save_screenshot()


    def get_and_save_screenshot(self):
        '''Some code to get a screenshot of the website on self.url'''

        self.screenshot.put(screenshot_file)
        self.save()
```

This way I was able to create new documents in mongo by just calling `new_urldoc = URLDoc(url="some url")` and then just `new_urldoc.save()`.

When I started loading existing documents from mongo by `URLDoc.objects.get(id="some id")` I realized that the `__init__` function will be triggered again set new data (take a new screenshot for example) in the document.

I want to implement this but only when the document is new, I looked up everywhere and couldn't find an answer..

Is there a way to call certain functions when initializing a **new** document as opposed to initializing an **existing** document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [mongoengine's documentations](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html?documents#documents), You can make sure a document is being loaded from the database if the `_created` kwarg is passed as `True` like this:

```
    def __init__(self, your_var, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print(kwargs)
        if not kwargs.get('_created', True):
            return  # Loaded from DB, No modification needed
        self.some_var = your_var
        # Initiate the brand new instance
```

note: this method that's been mentioned before does work, but only for Documents. EmbeddedDocuments do not have the `id` attribute!

```
if self.id: 
    print("loaded from DB")
else:
    print("Brand new instance!")
```

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a similar solution and after a while I found that MongoEngine supports [Signals](https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/signals.html). There are multiple signals that can be coupled with document before/after certain operations:

- initialization
- saving
- deletion

Unfortunately is does not support signals based on document update, but a workaround it is to check if the sender document has an id or not. A simple snippet code - based on the example in the MongoEngine documentation:

```
def update_modified(sender, document):
    if document.id: 
        document.modified = datetime.utcnow() # Will only be executed if the document has been already saved
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it working, I don't know if it's a work around or not but I check for `self._id` (an id is created only on save) on the init function and if there's none (meaning it's a new document), I set the values.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have it anymore. If I recall correctly, I added `if not self._id:` right after I called `super`. Hope that helps.